# How to change values of tabindex and aria-hidden depending on browser size?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wai-aria, tabindex

For desktop browser sizes I have a navbar across the top of the page, when browser reduces to mobile size it becomes a hamburger menu. As the menu is hidden at mobile size, then for accessibility reasons I believe that, the elements within the menu need to have attributes of `tabindex=-1` and `aria-hidden=true`. The website is being built using HTML/Jinja2, CSS, client side JS and Python/Flask.

As you can see from the CodePen below I am able to toggle the `aria-hidden` attribute once the menu has been opened.

[My demonstration repsonsive menu using CodePen] (https://codepen.io/janlikescodepen/pen/wvJmdBZ)

Comment: You could just use `display:none` on the menu list and toggle it when the menu is open, this removes the need for `aria-hidden`, `tabindex="-1"` etc. Also be aware that you need to give the menu button some text that a screen reader can understand (`aria-label="menu"`) and also add `aria-expanded="true"` when the menu is open. Finally to open the menu use a `<button>` not an anchor, that is an anti pattern (Quick rule: use an anchor if the URL changes, otherwise use a `<button>`).

Comment: @GrahamRitchie  I've gotten stuck trying to implement your idea, the nav wont display when I click on the hamburger button. Could you have a look at the following codepen https://codepen.io/janlikescodepen/pen/yLMKxZB
I like your idea it sounds like I shouldn't need to change much code and thank you for the extra accessibility tips!

Comment: Just found this on MDN " aria-hidden="true" should not be added when: the element or the element's ancestor is hidden with display: none" 
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-hidden_attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stuck on a similiar problem - wanting to creating a simple dropdown menu that does not disrupt the tabindex flow and screenreader flow, then my solution to this problem is using simple CSS + JS. The steps for it are:

1. At the mobile breakpoint the menu is hidden using `display:none;` and the hamburger is displayed
2. Clicking the hamburger calls a JS function that adds a CSS class to the menu that causes menu to be displayed because the class has `display:flex` and is lower down the stylesheet than the CSS style mentioned in step 1, therefore overriding it.
3. Clicking the hamburger calls the same JS function, but this time removes the class that was added in step 2, thus hiding the menu.

As suggested by QuentinC and Graham Ritchie, I used `display:none` instead of `height:0` to hide the menu because this solves the issues for keyboard only or screenreader users.

[View demo code in Codepen.][1]
[Codepen]

Notes:
If you are thinking of using JS to toggle `display:none`/`display:flex`, then I warn you that you might face some specificity issues. This was my initial attempt, but I encountered specificity issues that I could only resolve by using `!important`. Simply adding and removing a class, as per my example, does not create specificity issues because there is no inline styling or html `ID`.
[1]: https://codepen.io/janlikescodepen/pen/yLMKxZB

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the window `resize` event - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

As well as `window.innerWidth` - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/innerWidth

The `resize` event listens for when the window size changes, and the `innerWidth` will tell you  what size the window is so that you may conditionally modify the DOM depending on the window size.

Here is a simple example of what you may be looking to do -

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
    console.log('Window is greater than 800px');
  } else {
    console.log('Window is less than or equal to 800px')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and simplest is in fact to entirely rely on CSS display property and nothing else.

An element which isn't displayed because of display:none isn't focusable, nor readable by a screen reader either. That's implicit. You don't need to worry about aria-hidden or tabindex in this case, which is much easier.

You may use CSS property visibility instead of display, if you wish, the effect is the same.